# Can we create multiple cloudflare argo tunnel with different domains from same machine?

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-argo

I have multiple domains that points to single IP but since I don’t to expose my IP I want to use Argo Tunnel and achieve the same functionality(Point all domains to same server).

But the problem is, with Argo tunnel I am unable to add multiple domains. **I can’t create multiple tunnels with different domains to the same machine** as for one machine there is one certificate installed and **to initiate new argo tunnel previous certificate needs to be deleted**.

How can create tunnel for abc.com, xyz.com qrs.com with single server ?

Answer (score 3):

i have done this on my ubuntu cloud server. Follow these steps.

**Step 1:**
i moved the **~/.cloudflared/cert.pem** to **~/.cloudflared.cert.pem.abc.com**

**Step 2** ( authenticate new domain xyz.com )

run in terminal: ***cloudflared login***

once authenticated then run the follwing command to start the new tunnel

***sudo cloudflared tunnel --hostname xyz.com --url http://127.0.0.1***

you can also put this command in the background to keep it running in the background.

This will do the work you need but it has a problem.
the problem is that whenever you will restart or create any tunnel then you will require to add the cert.pem of that domain to this location ***~/.cloudflared/cert.pem*** and then you can start that tunnel. once the tunnel is running this file is no longer required.

so in this process it will require replacing the cert.pem file everytime you start a new tunnel or restart any existing one.

This is the onlyway to support multiple tunnels at same time or you can use [CNAME Setup](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020615111-How-do-I-do-CNAME-setup-) feature of cloudflare but that needs the plan to be Business or higher.